# ios show/hide notification if app is killed/running

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I know we cannot launch an app automatically from a push notification if the user has killed the app but if background app is killed by iOS (and not terminated by user), will iOS relaunch the app in background when a push notification is received?

If iOS wont relaunch the app, we would like to at least notify user that their app is killed so that they can click on the notification message to launch the app again.

To allow that, is there a way to hide notifications if the app is running (in foreground or background) and show the notification if the app is terminated (either by user or automatically by iOS)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app would be opened when the user tap in a notification doesn't matter if the app is in background or killed or not open since a device reboot.
On the other hand you can not show the notification when the app is in the foreground by checking the application state on `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`

To know about the way iOS manage notifications take a look at this methods
`application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`
`application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:`

and the guide: [Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot conditionally show or hide push notification based on state of background app. However, if the app has been kill by iOS or crash, it will still be awaken by push notification.